# Motion of a rigid body in three dimensions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, gyroscopes

I am doing [this problem](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jY6l0uC2-whcjzZwVWrYBksaswOKNK-Q). My solution is different from the author's solution. Here is my solution:

Choose a rotating reference frame Gxyz that **Gx is the x axis in CS Fig 18.1, Gx is fixed, Gy and Gz are rotating about Gx and their angular velocity is roll velocity $\omega_1$ = 30 rpm.** (I doubt my rotating reference frame is different from Gxyz in author's solution.) $\vec i, \vec j, \vec k$ are unit vector of Gxyz.

I calculate the angular momentum $H_G$ of the body with respect to the Earth:

$\vec H_G = I_x\omega_{roll}\vec i + I_z\omega_{pitch}\vec k $

Then I simply calculate time derivative of $\vec H_G$ that is $\dot {\vec H_G}$:

$\dot {\vec H_G} = \frac{d\vec H_G}{dt} = \frac{I_x\omega_{roll}}{dt}\vec i + \frac{I_z\omega_{pitch}}{dt}\vec k  + \vec \Omega \times \vec H_G$,

with $\vec \Omega$ is the angular velocity of the Gxyz with respect to Earth.
From definition of Gxyz, I have $\vec \Omega = \omega_{roll}\vec i$

So $\dot {\vec H_G} = (I_x*0)\vec i + (900*1.5708)\vec k +  \omega_{roll}\vec i \times (I_x\omega_{roll}\vec i + I_z\omega_{pitch}\vec k)$ (do you think I get the $\dot {\vec H_G}$ right?)

I have $\sum M_G = \dot {\vec H_G} = -5920.66\vec j + 1413.72\vec k $

Look at the author 's expanded equation (1):

$\sum M_G = I_x\dot \omega_x\vec i + I_y\dot \omega_y\vec i + I_z\dot \omega_z\vec i + (\omega_{roll}\vec i + \omega_{pitch}\vec k)\times \vec H_G$

I thought $\dot \omega_x, \dot \omega_y, \dot \omega_z$ are simply the scalar derivatives from $\vec H_G = I_x\omega_x\vec i + I_z\omega_z\vec k$ (you can see this from my solution). But the author get them from $\dot \omega$. I don't understand author's approach. I don't understand why author have to calculate $\dot \omega$. What am I misunderstanding ?